# Is Wolfram Alpha correct about this limit of an oscillating function?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, solution-verification, wolfram-alpha

I'm struggling with the following limit
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} e^x\big(1 + \sin(x)\big).$$

First of all I checked the solution using [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=limit%20e%5Ex%281%2Bsin%28x%29%29%20x%20%5Cto%20%5Cinfty). To my surprise Wolfram says that this limit exists and is equal to $\infty$. This goes against my intuition being honest.

I decided to try to show that this limit does not exist using Heine definition. I found the following sequences
$$x_n = n\pi, \qquad y_n = \bigg(2n + \frac{3}{2}\bigg)\pi.$$

Of course both $x_n$ and $y_n$ tend to $\infty$ whenever $n \to \infty$. Moreover we have $\sin(x_n) = 0$ and $\sin(y_n) = -1$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

The first limit is easy,
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} e^{x_n}\big(1 + \sin(x_n)\big) = \infty.$$

The problems appears when computing the next limit, which is
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} e^{y_n}\big(1 + \sin(y_n)\big).$$
We clearly have an indeterminate form, i.e. $\infty \times 0$. How can I solve my problem? Does this limit exist?

Comment: I think Wolfram is wrong. This function is (as you show)  $0$ infinitely often on an arithmetic progression and grows without bound on another. This has nothing to do with indeterminate forms.

Comment: @EthanBolker, you're right. So I need to find another $y_n$ I guess but it's quite hard.

Comment: It's not hard. There is no limit and your argument explains why. So there is no point in looking for "another $y_n$".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The given limit does NOT exist (and Wolfram is wrong).

As you already noted, $x_n = n\pi\to +\infty$ and
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} e^{x_n}\big(1 + \sin(x_n)\big) =+\infty.$$
On the other hand, if $y_n = \bigg(2n + \frac{3}{2}\bigg)\pi\to +\infty$ then, for any integer $n$,
$$e^{y_n}\big(1 + \sin(y_n)\big)=e^{(2n + \frac{3}{2})\pi}\big(1  -1\big)=0$$
and therefore (no indeterminate form here!)
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} e^{y_n}\big(1 + \sin(y_n)\big)=0.$$
So, along two sequences which go to $+\infty$, we obtain two different limits of $e^x\big(1 + \sin(x)\big)$, therefore $\lim_{x \to \infty} e^x\big(1 + \sin(x)\big)$ does not exist.

Comment: Thanks! That is what I was missing. Computing this limit in a standard way leads us to an indeterminate form however noticing that for every $n$ the sequence is equal to 0 allows us to find the limit. Thanks!